# javascript variable assign json url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

there is such a production.

```
var chats = [
  {
    text: 'Hi, dude!',
    position: 'left'
  },
  {
    text: 'Wat?',
    position: 'right'
  }],
```

I want to pull this structure from url.

My URL

```
[
  {
    text: 'Hi, dude!',
    position: 'left'
  },
  {
    text: 'Wat?',
    position: 'right'
  },
  {
    text: 'You wanna know?',
    position: 'left'
  },
  {
    text: 'Wat?!',
    position: 'right'
  }
]
```

How can I assign this to the chats variable?

Comment: Do you want to split the response Array by ‚position‘?

Comment: How about `var chats = { "message" : [ ... ] }`

Comment: why not concat it like this: let merged = json1.concat(json2);

Comment: *My URL* - that's not an URL

Comment: JSON url is something new ...

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: the upper static comes from the lower dynamic. I don't need to join here.

Comment: @JaromandaX the upper static comes from the lower dynamic. I don't need to join here.